# Stata: how to calculate output of r(alpha) (short example included)?

Tags: stata

I'm not a Stata user, but just trying to decipher existing code

## Input data:

[image: Input data]

## Code:

```
import excel "\\inputdata.xlsx", firstrow case(lower)


levelsof category, l(smoothingcategory)

foreach i of local smoothingcategory { 
    keep if etype==1 & value != . & category==`i'

    tsset year
    tssmooth exponential smoothed=value, samp0(2) forecast(1)
    gen parameter=r(alpha)

    if (parameter > .5 & avg_freq > 50) {
        drop smoothed parameter
        tssmooth exponential smoothed=value, parms(.5) samp0(2) forecast(1)
        gen parameter=r(alpha)
    }
    else if (avg_freq < 50 & parameter > .1) {
        drop smoothed parameter
        tssmooth exponential smoothed=value, parms(.1) samp0(2) forecast(1)
        gen parameter=r(alpha)
    }
    
    replace category=`i' if missing(category)
}
```

## Output, Question

Can someone please explain (preferably with Excel formulas but I'll take anything) how "smoothed" and "parameter" are calculated?
[output][2

Comment: Hello! Welcome to the Stata tag in StackOverflow. You are more likely to get help here if you include a reproducible example. Especially as it is quite straightforward to do so in your case. See the section on data in screenshots in the Stata tag here : https://stackoverflow.com/tags/stata/info

Comment: There is a detailed write-up at https://www.stata.com/manuals/tstssmoothexponential.pdf -- which you can access even if you don't have access to Stata.

Comment: Cross-posted at https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1711404-how-to-calculate-output-of-r-alpha-short-example-included